# Псевдоним для переменной

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, phpstorm, jetbrains

В проекте, в котором я работаю, название переменных представляют из себя 1 символ.
Существует ли расширение, с помощью которого, можно было бы сделать псевдоним для переменной для более легкого чтения кода?

например:

```
$n = 2;
$n*=4;
```

Я пишу для `n` псевдоним `number` и получаю:

```
$number = 2;
$number*=4;
```

Очевидно, что речь идет не про переименование в коде, а именно про локальный псевдоним, который будет только у меня

Comment: в phpstorm можно настроить алиасы как душе угодно

Comment: Ну и чем `number` лучше чем `n`?

Comment: @Qwertiy может быть тем, что это абстрактный упрощенный пример? И тем, что речь явно не про n и number идет?

Comment: File | Settings | Editor | Live Templates